# Azure service bus - Set polling time for AMQP protocol

Tags: java, azureservicebus, amqp

My understanding is that when using Azure Service Bus in a Queue configuration, it uses polling to check if there are any new messages in the queue. Each poll is counted as a operation on the Azure service bus and for a low volume system, it is money down the drain.

Is it possible to setup Azure Service Bus using AMQP protocol to use Publisher-Consumer design pattern? If not, is it possible to set a long polling time so that it tries to check for messages every 5 mins.

I have gone through Microsoft documentation on this and have not been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus will send a little bit of data every minute to keep the connection open. That isn't free, but is pennies per month for each listener. You could set up your own polling loop that doesn't use long polling and check at any interval you would like.

Logic Apps does something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus)- if no messages are found, it will wait for an interval you set to check again.

If you would prefer to move to a push model instead of pub-sub, then I would suggest looking at [Event Grid](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-event-grid-the-whole-story-4b7b4ec4ad23#:%7E:text=Azure%20Event%20Grid%20supports%20a,to%20events%20as%20they%20happen.) instead.